# What is 1PC baggage allowance for Jetstar Asia Air?

Tags: luggage, jetstar

I booked on the Travel up travel agency and have a flight from Denpasar to Singapore and i cannot find the weight allowance. Travel up says i have 1PC but it does not specify what this is. I was able to find out the allowance for British airways and Hong Kong air.

Answer (score 3):

[Carry-on allowance](http://www.jetstar.com/au/en/help/tags/carry-on-baggage) is 7kg for Economy Starter, Starter Plus and Starter Max passengers, 7kg plus a second small item for FlexiBiz* passengers and 14kg for Business Class.

[Checked baggage allowance](http://www.jetstar.com/au/en/help/articles/is-checked-baggage-allowance-included-in-my-fare) depends on your class

- Economy starter - not included
- Economy Starter fare with Plus bundle - 20kg
- Economy Starter fare with Max bundle - 30kg
- Economy Starter fare with FlexiBiz bundle - not included
- Business fare and Business fare with Max bundle - not included

In the second link there are details about additional baggage you can purchase.

Answer (score 2):

1PC means "one piece".

The airline website should state clearly any weight or dimensions restrictions. Which is your flight number? Some airlines apply different baggage allowance (weight limits, number of pieces, etc) depending on the flight, type of ticket, etc.